# Close MySQL connection via Thread

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I have a problem with my code, my program fills a JTable form a MySQL DB using a thread, the program works fine but I get this error

//Error, com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLNonTransientConnectionException: Data source rejected establishment of connection,  message from server: "Too many connections"
Error java.lang.NullPointerException//

I think I need to close the connection or maybe don't use a Thread for fills the JTable, my idea it's fills the table with out using a JButton event, do you have a suggestion for this?

```
public class VentanaAdministrador extends javax.swing.JFrame{

    public static final String URL = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/floreria?autoReconnet=true&useSSL=false";
    public static final String Usuario = "root";
    public static final String Contraseña = "";
    PreparedStatement ps;
    ResultSet rs;
    
    public Connection getConnection(){
        Connection conexion = null;
        
        try{
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            conexion = (Connection) DriverManager.getConnection(URL,Usuario,Contraseña);
        }catch(Exception ex){
            System.err.println("Error, "+ex);
        }
        
        return conexion;
    }
    ///////////////////////////////////////////////
    Thread llenado = new Thread(){
        public void run(){
        DefaultTableModel modeloTabla = new DefaultTableModel();
        TablaVentanaAsignar.setModel(modeloTabla);
        
        PreparedStatement ps = null;
        ResultSet rs = null;
        
        
        try{
            VentanaAdministrador con = new VentanaAdministrador();
            Connection VentanaAdministrador = con.getConnection();
            
            ps = VentanaAdministrador.prepareStatement("select NumeroEmpleado,Nombre,Punto_de_venta,TiempoTrabajo from empleados where Puesto=?");
            ps.setString(1, "Diseñador");
            rs = ps.executeQuery();
            
            modeloTabla.addColumn("No. Empleado");
            modeloTabla.addColumn("Nombre");
            modeloTabla.addColumn("Sucursal");
            modeloTabla.addColumn("Tiempo trabajado");
            
            while(rs.next()){
                Object fila[] = new Object[4];
                fila[0] = rs.getObject(1);
                fila[1] = rs.getObject(2);
                fila[2] = rs.getObject(3);
                fila[3] = rs.getObject(4);
                
                modeloTabla.addRow(fila);
            }   
            }catch(Exception ex){
                    System.err.println("Error "+ex);
                    
        }
        }
    };    
    
    public VentanaAdministrador() {
        initComponents();
        llenado.start();
    }
```

Comment: You need to close the connection as soon as you have finished with it, i.e. after your `catch` block, in a `finally` block: or better still use try-with-resources. NB Neither the `PreparedStatement` nor the `ResultSet` should be member variables. NB 2 The `Class.forName()` line hasn't been needed since 2007.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generally best in database work to focus on doing the following as quickly and directly as practical:

- (a) connect to database,
- (b) execute query,
- (c) retrieve data, and
- (d) terminate connection (or return connection to pool if you are using connection-pooling).

So there is no need to carry a `PreparedStatement` and `ResultSet` as member fields on your class as seen in your code. Such objects should be rapidly instantiated, utilized, and discarded (generally speaking).

[Separate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns) your database work from your [GUI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graphical_user_interface) work. Interacting with the database can take a while, so run that on the background thread. When complete, use the appropriate access point in your GUI to ask that it update its widgets with the fresh data — but update itself within its own GUI thread. **Never access a GUI widget from another thread.** Whether you are using [JavaFX/OpenJFX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaFX), [Swing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Swing_(Java)), [SWT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_Widget_Toolkit), [Vaadin Flow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vaadin#Vaadin_Flow), or [Android](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_software_development), each GUI framework has a hook for asking the GUI to update its widgets on the GUI's own thread.

In modern Java we rarely need to address the `Thread` class directly. For concurrent work, use the *Executors* framework added to Java 5.

You'll get the most flexibility in development, testing, and deployment if you use the [`DataSource`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.sql/javax/sql/DataSource.html) interface to contain connection info rather than mere strings as seen in your code. Usually a [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) provides a basic implementation of `DataSource`. For example, the [*Connector/J* driver provides](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/8.0/en/connector-j-reference-configuration-properties.html) `com.mysql.cj.jdbc.MysqlDataSource` class.

```java
private DataSource prepareDataSource() {
    MysqlDataSource ds = new com.mysql.cj.jdbc.MysqlDataSource();
    ds.setServerName( "1.2.3.4" );
    ds.setPortNumber( 5432 );
    ds.setUser( "scott" );
    ds.setPassword( "tiger") ;
    ds.setDatabaseName( "invoicing" );
    … Set all your relevant properties …
    return ds ;
}
```

Keep this `DataSource` around in a handy place within your app, to be used by whatever code needs a database connection.

Also keep handy an implementation of [`ExecutorService`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html) to be used for your background threading work. Use [`Executors`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/Executors.html) utility class to conveniently obtain an instance. Be sure to eventually shutdown the executor service before your app exits, as its backing thread pool may otherwise continue running indefinitely like a zombie.

```
ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool( 3 ) ;
```

Or, in the future when [*Project Loom*](https://wiki.openjdk.java.net/display/loom/Main) technology arrives:

```
ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newVirtualThreadExecutor() ;
```

Use [try-with-resources](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) syntax when doing JDBC work. It simplifies your code in helpful ways, automatically closing your database resources.

Define your database work as a task object implementing the [`Runnable`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Runnable.html) (or `Callable`) interface. Submit an instance to your executor service.

```java
/// Code in your GUI detects need to load data.
/// … Fetch the `ExecutorService` from wherever you stored it.
executorService.submit( new DatabaseWorkRunnable() ) ;
```

The [`run`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Runnable.html#run()) method of that `Runnable` might look like something like this incomplete and untested code seen below.

Notice how this code has a nested pair of try-with-resources statements covering three [`AutoCloseable`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/AutoCloseable.html) resource objects: a `Connection`, a `PreparedStatement`, and a `ResultSet`. If instantiated, each resource object will be closed whether or not your code completes successfully. The resources are closed in the reverse order in which they were declared.

The `DataSource` object is not a resource and is never “open”. So it is never closed. A `DataSource` simply holds information for opening a connection to the database.

```java
String sql = "SELECT … ;";
try (
        Connection conn = dataSource.getConnection() ;
        PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatement( sql ) ;
)
{
    … Make `PreparedStatement::set…` calls here.
    try (
            ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery() ;
    )
    {
        if ( rs.next() )
        {
            LocalDate ld = rs.getObject( 1 , LocalDate.class );
            … Retrieve your data , add to collection to be delivered to GUI later.
        }
    }
}
catch ( SQLException e )
{
    e.printStackTrace();
}
// At this point, all three `Connection`, `PreparedStatement`, and `ResultSet` objects are closed automatically whether your code ran successfully or whether an exception/error was thrown.

… Use your GUI framework’s hook to ask the GUI to update its table widget with the fresh data in collection.
```

All this has been covered many times already on Stack Overflow. Search to learn more and see many examples.